# Using the polynomial of lowest order that interpolates $f(x)$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$, derive a numerical integration formula for $\int_{x_0}^{x_3}f(x)dx$.

Tags: integration, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

Using the polynomial of lowest order that interpolates $f(x)$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$, derive a numerical integration formula for $\int_{x_0}^{x_3}f(x)dx$.

I know that we aren't assuming uniform spacing. We know that $x_0<x_1<x_2<x_3$. I think a linear equation will be the way to go. I'm not sure how to do this. Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the (linear) polynomial that interpolates $f$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$? Once you have it you can use this to find the integral $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f_{\rm interpol}(x) {\rm d}x$ and then sum up over the intervals in question $[x_0,x_1]$, $\ldots$, $[x_2,x_3]$.

Comment: Is it $f(x)=y_0+(y_1-y_0){{x-x_0} \over {x_1-x_0}}$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. That is the linear polynomial that agrees with $f$ on the two points $x=x_0$ and $x=x_1$. Now you can try to integrate it over $[x_0,x_1]$ to find an approximation of the integral $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x){\rm d}x$.

Comment: Since I want $f(x)$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$ shouldn't I say $f(x)=y_1+(y_2-y_1){x-x_1 \over x_2-x_1}$ and then just compute $\int_{x_0}^{x_3}f(x)dx$?

Comment: I might have misread the problem. I assumed you were to find the interpolating polynomial on each of the intervals $[x_0,x_1]$, $[x_1,x_2]$ and $[x_2,x_3]$ and then sum up the resulting integrals. This will give you the so called [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Uniform_grid). If you are to only use the points $x_1,x_2$ then it's even simpler and just as you said above.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much for your help

Comment: No worries. btw you might want to post an answer to your own question below once you have solved it completely. That way the question has an answer and people can upvote it if it's good. You can also accept your own answer if nobody posts (what you think is) a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote in a comment, the polynomial to use is $$p(x)=y_1+\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1),\quad y_i=f(x_i)$$ 
Plug this into    $\int_{x_0}^{x_3}p(x)dx$ to get 
$$y_1(x_3-x_0)+\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\frac{(x_3-x_1)^2-(x_0-x_1)^2}{2}$$
which is the required approximation to the integral of $f$.

---

In the special case $x_1=x_0$ and $x_2=x_3$ this simplifies to 
$$ \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}(x_3-x_0)  $$ which is the Trapezoidal rule.